# Running function only if a certain element isn't burring

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

im making an application that creates a text input where ever you click. I was having a problem where whenever you would click inside the field another text field would appear but i managed to fix that. I have one last major issue that I just can't solve. I know ou can't use blur() and focus() as arguments (though it would be nice) but i need to find a way so that after you enter text into the input field and out click, it just blurs the input box and doesn't create another until the user clicks again.

Comment: What do you mean you can't use `blur()` and `focus()` as arguments.. arguments to what?

Answer (score 0):

Just create a variable to keep track or only use a certain ID for the input you create, then check for that variable or input element before creation..

```
if(!$("#myDynamicInputElement").length){
    //TODO: Create your element..
}
```